# run time error - non zero exception

Tags: c++, c, arrays, error-handling, runtime

my programming teacher gave me this problem to code it in c : 
given array of N integers A and a number K. During a turn the maximal value over all `Ai` is chosen, let's call it MAX. Then Ai =
`MAX - Ai` is done for every `1 <= i <= N`. Help Roman to find out how will the array look like after `K` turns.

Input

The numbers N and K are given in the first line of an input. Then N integers are given in the second line which denote the array A.

Output

Output N numbers on a single line. It should be the array A after K turns.

Constraints

```
* 1 <= N <= 10^5
* 0 <= K <= 10^9
* Ai does not exceed 2 * 10^9 by it's absolute value.
```

Example

```
Input:
4 1
5 -1 7 0

Output:
2 8 0 7
```

and my code to this problem is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>


long int Max(long int *arr, int low, int high)
{
long int max,i;

max = arr[low];
for(i=0;i<=high;i++)
{
    if(max<=arr[i])
      max = arr[i];
}

  return max;
}

 /* Driver program to test above function */
 int main()
 {
    long int max,*arr;
    long int n,k,c1,c2,c3,i,j;

    c1 = (long int)pow(10,5);
    c2 = (long int)pow(10,9);
    c3 = 2*c2;
    scanf("%ld %ld",&n,&k);

    if(n<1||n>c1)
      exit(1);
    else if(k<0||k>c2)
      exit(1);
    else
    {
    arr = (long int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
        scanf("%ld",&arr[i]);
        if(abs(arr[i])>c3)
          exit(1);
      }
    if(k%2 == 0)
      {
        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            max = Max(arr, 0, n-1);
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {   
                arr[j] = max-arr[j];
                if(abs(arr[j])>c3)
                            exit(1);
            }
        }
      }
    else if(k%2 != 0)
    {
        max = Max(arr, 0, n-1);
                    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                       {       
                        arr[j] = max-arr[j];
                            /*if(abs(arr[j])>c3)
                              exit(1);*/
                       }
    }
    /*  for(m=0;m<n;m++)
                printf("%ld ",arr[m]);
        printf("\n");*/

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      printf("%ld ",arr[i]);

    printf("\n");
   }  
   return 0;
 }
```

i executed this code on `gcc` compiler in `ubuntu`, it is working perfectly with all the constraints satisfied but when I uploaded this code on my teacher's portal which has a compiler and executed the code, it said `Runtime` error -

`nzec which means a non-zero exception which is used to signify that main() does not have "return 0;" statement or exception thrown by c++ compiler`.

Please, can anyone help me what is wrong in my code as there is a return 0; statement in my code. Please Help.

Everyone has pointed out multiple use of exits ... Can I reduce them using any other way in place of exit()?

Comment: `long int` and `int` are not necessarily the same size.

Comment: @Marco: but if i want to exit the code if any of these conditions are not satisfied then what should i do ? i have tried using different exit non-zero values as exit with a non-zero value is an abnormal termination but still nothing is happening. and is it that we can't use multiple times exit with same value.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson :  i did not understand from your comment. i know that long int and int are not same size so that's why i have declared all the variables as long int because i have to check constraint values, that are given in the question, which can't be accommodated in int

Comment: Yes, but you've set `arr` to point to memory allocated for `n` _integers_, not `n` _long integers_. That may very well corrupt memory and give the error you're getting. `sizeof(int)` <= `sizeof(long int)`, ie you may very well be allocating less memory than you're using.

Comment: It is a question from codechef. I hope codechef is not your teacher http://www.codechef.com/MAY14/problems/CHEFBM

Comment: @jahan : i know that very well that it is the questions from codechef may challenge 2014 but my teacher has asked us to solve these questions as the part of our assignment, that's why based on which we will be marked.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson : yes, i corrected that mistake after Alter Mann pointed it out. Thanks but can u see any other mistake.

Comment: @POOJAGUPTA Tell your teacher that the contest is going on and it is against the rules to discuss any where. See [here] (http://www.codechef.com/MAY14/). I have solution in c++ for the problem.

Comment: The input constraints are guarantees given to you. You don't need to verify them unless your teacher explicitly told you to. They give you hints about variable ranges, e.g. you know from them that Ai will fit in a signed `int`.

Comment: It is a codechef contest question. So you are not allowed to discuss such questions during contest. I have efficient solution in C. So could not discuss it now. But for hints, check for the boundary conditions using boundary test cases.

Comment: @UtkalSinha : i did not know that ... so i will not discuss it further .

Comment: @jahan : i will not further discuss this question but do i have to now scrap off this question from stack overflow . sorry i did not know it earlier.

Comment: @UtkalSinha : if you can see my code i am checking boundary conditions. is there anything wrong in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it has to do with the various `exit(1)` statements you have for error conditions.

Comment: but it is still giving the same error .... can you see any other mistake in my code? if any, please tell me that.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Dave Costa, `exit(1)` could be the cause

Another possible problem is the size of the allocated array:

```
arr = (long int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

should be:

```
arr = malloc(sizeof(long int)*n);
```

And note that you don't need to use `pow` for constants:

```
c1 = (long int)pow(10,5);
c2 = (long int)pow(10,9);
```

could be replaced with:

```
c1 = 1e5L;
c2 = 1e9L;
```

Comment: : thanks for pointing out that mistake. i have corrected it but now still it is saying same error.